# Unable to load image after template is rendered using Router in Meteor

Tags: image, templates, meteor, router

I'm running Meteor 0.6.6.1, using the package [Router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router) and all my images are in the *public* folder.
My issue is: when I'm in the URL root (`http://localhost:3000`), after the template is rendered, I am able to load an image, as illustrated using the console in the image below:

[image: Able to load image when in URL root]

But when I'm in another URL (`http://localhost:3000/orderProduct/frame1`) using the Router to drive the right template, I can't load the same image after the template is rendered, as shown in the image below:

[image: Unable to load image when in a route address]

As we can see from the console's output, the only difference is the well known Chrome's warning about the content type.

I would like to load the images in a routed URL after the template is rendered. Someone can help me, please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your post and show some code ?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use relative URLs for images, the ones that does not start with `/`. In this case, browser search for the image RELATIVE to the current document path. So in the second case, it search in the `orderProduct` folder, which does not exist - and hence the error. See what's the image URL the browser tries to fetch, it's different in the two examples.

To solve your problem use absolute path, the one starting with `/`:

```
$('body').append('<img src="/imageName.png">');
```

In this case, the browser will look for the photo in the given path on the current server, and it will find it regardless on what's the current page address.

Comment: Solved! I knew that Meteor provide all content from *public* folder in `/`, but I have forget to put this address in the image src. Thanks a lot, @Hubert OG!